# Series resistor vs PCB track impedance

Tags: voltage, resistance, impedance, layout, characteristic-impedance

I want to understand the below question:

There are digital interface for example, MII/RMII lines. It requires a PCB characteristic impedance of 50 Ω.

Also, better EMC flexibility, it is said to place some series termination resistors of, say 33 Ω. In that case, does the line have (50+33) 83 Ω as the impedance at the point of the resistor? Or should the resistor take into account the characteristic trace impedance also?

Comment: If you looking for an explanation of the **question**, then where did you find it?

Answer (score 1):

These interfaces are (at least, as far as I know) just plain old LVCMOS inputs and outputs.

The output resistance is approx. 30-70Ω, depending on pin state, instantaneous output voltage, and manufacturing variation.

Typically, the chosen scheme for the bus is source-terminated transmission lines, for which the impedance of the traces isn't very important (most anything in the 50-100Ω range typical of PCB traces over ground plane will do), and which requires a little resistance added in series with the pin driver to guarantee an impedance match in the worst case (which eliminates overshoot).  At the other extreme, risetime is increased (undershoot occurs), which needs to be checked that it meets the receiver maximum rise/fall time spec.

The resistor value is a compromise between overshoot vs. undershoot at process extremes, and of having low enough risetime at the receiver to meet its requirements.

Using the slowest risetime possible in an application has some merit -- use only the bandwidth you require -- particularly to avoid emissions issues.  There is the downside that receivers are more sensitive to noise, as they are closer to their switching threshold for longer during the slow risetime.  There can be some compromise in terms of EMC emissions vs. susceptibility here as well.

When possible, you can minimize the length of the bus, which also avoids issues of timing skew, radiation from traces (as antennae), etc.  For traces much shorter (in terms of electrical length) than the output pin risetime, source termination resistors aren't really meaningful, and the traces act like tiny capacitors (most likely, tiny enough not to even notice).  For most LVCMOS output pins, risetime is in the 0.5-3ns range, so this critical length is several cm or more.

Answer (score 1):

These series resistors can be very important for signal integrity (I had to learn it the hard way )

They help reducing signal ringing/overshoot when your driver has very low rise time (which is usually the case with 50MHz RMII).

There are two things that the resistors provide:

1. Together with the capacitance of the trace, they form a low pass filter which by its definition prevents HF ringing.
2. The very low driver output impedance is increased in a way that it matches the characteristic impedance of the trace. This is called impedance matching. So it‘s not 33+50 ohms, but rather 33 + driver impedance equals 50 ohms. This minimizes signal reflection and thus ringing.

Comment: Surely you mean *low* rise time, i.e. fast edges?

Comment: Or maybe he was referring to rise times as in V/us?  Though I would call that edge rate.

Comment: Yes, I meant low rise time of course. Thanks, I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

An RMII interface (running at 50MHz, MII run's half as slow at 25MHz and you should be able to route MII on just about anything) should not require a characteristic impedance. What should be done is to minimize rise times by minimizing capacitance in the layout. Route these traces adjacent to a ground layer and use a continuous ground. You may want to place a series resistor (22Ω or 50Ω to eliminate ringing) on each line.

Comment: Routing the traces adjacent to a ground layer will maximize capacitance, which is contrary to the first thing you said. Are you sure this is the way?